# best method to manipulate array keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array. I need to add ':' to the start of all the keys.
What would be the fastest/simplest way of doing this?
And what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is it for output purposes? If so,why not do it in the view/template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the simplest way would probably be to build a new array:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $newArray[":" . $key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($oldarray as $key => $value) $newarray[':' . $key] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
     $my_array = [
        1 => 'One',
        2 => 'Two',
        3 => 'Three',
        4 => 'Four',
        5 => 'Five'
    ];

    array_walk($my_array, function ($value, $key) use (&$new_array) {
        $new_array[':' . $key] = $value;
    });
```

Comment: The foreach solution, while not "functional"  way more easier to read, and speed differences are probably negligble.
Notice I asked this 10 years ago, I am "somewhat" more experienced today, functional programming is nice, but the example you brought is one of the pitfulls of that paradigm.